# Sums of areas of unit pythagorean triangles

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can the sum of the area of two rational unit (as in length of hypotenuse) pythagorean triangles be the area of another rational unit pythagorean triangle? It is known that the pythagorean triangles with hypotenuse 1 have side lengths of the form $$(\frac{2x}{x^2+1}, \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1})$$ Thus the area of these triangles must be $$\frac{2x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ So what I'm asking is: Is there rational x, y, and z such that: $$\frac{2x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2} + \frac{2y(y^2-1)}{(y^2+1)^2}=\frac{2z(z^2-1)}{(z^2+1)^2}$$

I'm interested in this because it is closely linked to the construction of a 3x3 magic square of squares. Specifically, if a solution to the above problem were found, I could construct a magic square with 7 square entries (the non-square entries will be opposite), and finding a complete magic square of squares reduces to finding four rational numbers w, x, y, z such that: $$\frac{2x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2} + \frac{2y(y^2-1)}{(y^2+1)^2}=\frac{2z(z^2-1)}{(z^2+1)^2}$$ and $$\frac{2w(w^2-1)}{(w^2+1)^2} + \frac{2x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{2y(y^2-1)}{(y^2+1)^2}$$ So if my original problem turns out to have no solution, I can show that there is no magic square of squares.

Comment: Should such numbers be positive?

Comment: Negating the numbers only negates the area, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: The answer to the existence question is yes: $x=y=z=1$ satisfies your equation. But perhaps you wish to enforce some further conditions.

Comment: According to http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath417.htm and other links this is an open problem. I searched for all rational $x,y,z$ of height $\leq 500$ and didn't find any nontrivial solution $x,y,z \not\in \{0,\pm 1\}$.

Comment: I checked for heights up to 213281 and found no solutions.

Comment: I checked among all Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ with $c\le 3000000$ and no solutions. The trick is in sorting all prime triples with $c\le 3000000$ by the max prime factor of $c$; if 2 triples have areas ($ab/c^2$) adding up to that of a 3rd triple, then at least 2 of the 3 must share the same max prime; so the search is limited to checking all sums and differences of 2 areas with equal max prime, whether they exist in a hash table of all areas (hashed as pairs of coprime integers, with unlimited precision, rather than as floats.) I could push my computation further, but is there a point?

Comment: A further link containing a routine to compute candidates (in Pari/GP) finding the 7-squares solutions in 53 secs can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123203/3-times-3-magic-square-of-squares?noredirect=1&lq=1